# Delete folders in subfolders

Tags: batch

I have about 3000 folders 
Each folder contains

> titlefolder
>
> typefolder
>
> -content

I need to get rid of the typefolder and have the content moved up one to the titlefolder. I know I can copy and paste and delete but having more then 3000 files to do individually that will take days. 
 Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: Is content only files or also directories from which the structure should be preserved? How many titlefolders and typefolders are we talking about?

Comment: Content only folder just contains about 6 files each all a different format no folders within. The titlefolders and typefolders there are about 3000 of them.

Comment: Can you take a screen shot of part of the folder structure? I'm not sure I'm reading the question right.

Comment: One could conceivably create a Python script that would do this. But there might be certain "things" (name collisions mostly) that may require extra work. As Patrick suggested, please provide a concrete example.

Comment: How many titlefolders are we talking about? Is it a lot titlefolders with few typefolders each or is it only few titlefolders each with a lot of typefolders?